# possible to delete or archive career messages?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I currently have a few messages in my careers.stackoverflow.com account, including a few from a few months back.

[image: The Messages Inbox I am talking about]

The only choices that the checkboxes next to each mail thread enable would be "Mark Unread" or "Mark Read".  There's no way to archive or delete a mail thread from this list.

And this is obviously by design, but I don't understand the rationale because there's no explanation in the [Careers FAQ for Programmers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq). It may be that the rationale is because you guys want me to remember where I applied to or who I've already talked with?

But in any event, it seems like this functionality should be added or -- much easier -- the design decision explained in the FAQ.

Comment: Guess they're just following the same behavior of Stack Exchange inbox messages or notifications: you receive them, you can read them but you can't delete them.

Comment: Was just wondering this myself this evening.  Would be nice to be able to archive old messages or at least delete irrelevant messages.